# installschema wont create table even though it is being called magento 2

Tags: magento2

I had created a sample module when I tried to create table I knew I have to delete the entry from my setup_module table or else the install schema wont run so.

`DELETE from setup_module where module='Mastering_SampleModule'`

After that I performed 
`sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade;`

Everthing runs fine, the module is being created again in the setup_module table as I check from

`select * from setup_module WHERE module= 'Mastering_SampleModule'`

but the table is not being created .

on trying to introduce error in installschema class and then running `sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade` the error is shown in the console according to error introduced and it is irrelevant. But table is not being created as expected if I run

`sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade;`

 command without any errors.

```
<?php

namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Setup ;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

        public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $table = $setup->getConnection()
                ->newTable($setup->getTable('mastering_sample_item)'))
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['identity'=>true,'nullable'=>false,'primary'=>true],
                    'Table Id'
                )->addColumn(
                    'name',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable'=>false],
                    'Table Name'

                )->addIndex(
                    $setup->getIdxName('mastering_sample_item',['name']),
                    ['name']

                )->setComment(
                    'Sample Items'
                );

            $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
            $setup->endSetup();
        } 
    }
```

I think there is any error in my install method , can someone tell me how to debug installschema and upgrade schema classes?

Comment: are you creating a new module or upgrading ?

Comment: i am creating a new module and the row has been inserted in the setup_module table before , i just want to create a simple table . i need to run install schema again.

Comment: Please check my ans for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below code in you **InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php


namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $table_mastering_samplemodule_sample_item = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('mastering_samplemodule_sample_item'));


        $table_mastering_samplemodule_sample_item->addColumn(
            'sample_item_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
            'Entity ID'
        );



        $table_mastering_samplemodule_sample_item->addColumn(
            'item1',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'item1'
        );



        $table_mastering_samplemodule_sample_item->addColumn(
            'item2',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            [],
            'item2'
        );


        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table_mastering_samplemodule_sample_item);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I have created sample module for you please get it from below url

https://mage2gen.com/download/ffe0dd25-4ac3-4b4f-a797-7fdc8cc1b3f8.tar

Comment: used your installschema.php but still nothing , the row in the setup module is being created as before  without creating the table  select * from mastering_samplemodule_sample_item shows that the table doesn't exist;

Comment: I have tried in my local and it is working fine for me

Comment: so i guess the problem is not in the installSchema.php file  , Could you suggest any way how to debug the module ? i am clueless here what to do as everything seems working fine , thanks .

Comment: please get module link from my ans, I have created it for you

Comment: @Ritesh did you get the module ?

Comment: thanks its working great , could you have a look at my module and guide me what i am doing wrong , its just a basic module 
 https://we.tl/PipCUeaNzA